# How to make the GameObject Stop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made this simple script for enemy AI. I want the enemy to stop rotating and moving towards us whenever he's attacking. How do I write it ?
The code is down below.

> ```
> using System.Collections;
> using UnityEngine;
>
> public class Chasev2 : MonoBehaviour {
>
>     public Transform Player;
>     public float Attack_range=8.5f;
>     public float Chase_range=50.0f; //How far ahead the enenmy can see
>     public float Distance;
>     public float rotation_speed=10.0f;
>     private Animator anim;
>     public float move_speed=10.0f;
>
>
>     // Use this for initialization
>     void Start () {
>         anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
>     }
>
>     // Update is called once per frame
>     void Update () {
>         anim.SetBool ("Run", true);
>         anim.SetBool ("Idle", false);
>         anim.SetBool ("Attack", false);
>         Distance = (Player.transform.position - transform.position).magnitude;
>         if (Distance <= Chase_range && Distance > Attack_range)
>         {
>             Vector3 Direction = Player.position - transform.position;
>             Direction.y = 0;
>             transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation (Direction), rotation_speed * Time.deltaTime);
>             transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
>             transform.position += transform.forward * move_speed * Time.deltaTime;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             anim.SetBool ("Run", false);
>             anim.SetBool ("Idle", true);
>             anim.SetBool ("Attack", false);
>         }
>         if (Distance < Attack_range)
>         {
>             anim.SetBool ("Run", false);
>             anim.SetBool ("Attack", true);
>             anim.SetBool ("Idle", false);
>         }
>     }
>
>
> void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
>     {
>         Gizmos.color = Color.red;
>             Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (transform.position,Attack_range);
>
>         Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
>             Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (transform.position,Chase_range);
>
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Can't really test this out right now, but try putting the attackrange condition as an else if.

Like so:

```
'if (Distance <= Chase_range && Distance > Attack_range)
{
    Vector3 Direction = Player.position - transform.position;
    Direction.y = 0;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation (Direction), rotation_speed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    transform.position += transform.forward * move_speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
else if (Distance < Attack_range)
{
    anim.SetBool ("Run", false);
    anim.SetBool ("Attack", true);
    anim.SetBool ("Idle", false);
}
else
{
    anim.SetBool ("Run", false);
    anim.SetBool ("Idle", true);
    anim.SetBool ("Attack", false);
}
```

`

I'd suggest you learn about using FSMs to make it much easier and cleaner for growing your AI even more ;)